# upload/download audio from firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an audio and download it later.
I am using firebase server for this process.

There are 2 queries i am stuck with. Solution to any one would solve the purpose:

1. How to upload the file as file instead of blob. I believe there should be a way to upload the file as it is, instead of first converting the file to blob and then uploading(which is i am doing right now).
2. I am able to download the file but not able to play it. Since the file was first converted to DataURL/ArrayBuffer and then uploaded, how can i convert it back to audio(mp3/wav)?

The code to upload:

```
  $scope.uploadFile = function(){ // uploading file
var storageRef= firebase.storage().ref();
var filename= $scope.audio.src.substring($scope.audio.src.lastIndexOf("/")+1,$scope.audio.src.length);
$scope.fname= filename;
// fetching file to upload
baseServ.dirEntry.getFile(filename, {}, function(entry){
  entry.file(function(gotfile){
    var reader= new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend= function(resultFile){
      console.log(resultFile);
      var blob= new Blob([resultFile], {type:"audio/mp3"});
      // uploading to firebase server
      var uploadTask = storageRef.child(filename).put(blob);
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
        console.log("state_changed:" + filename + "::::Current State:" +snapshot.state);
      }, function(error) {
        alert("upload error");
      }, function() {
        $scope.downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
      });
    }
    //reading as dataUrl or ArrayBuffer
    reader.readAsDataURL(gotfile);
  })
});
```

}

And to download:

```
  $scope.downloadFile= function(){
var ft= new FileTransfer();
ft.download($scope.downloadURL, baseServ.dirDownloads.nativeURL + $scope.fname, function(entry) {
  // download is successful but unable to play when opening in my device
    console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
},
function(error) {
    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
},
false,
{});
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Realtime Database is the wrong tool for storing audio files.  You should use Firebase Storage for that.  See [Firebase Features](https://firebase.google.com/features/).

> Store and retrieve user-generated content like images, audio and video
>   directly from the Firebase client SDK.
>
> Robust uploads and downloads in the background, regardless of network
>   quality Secure client-side authorization, integrated with
>   Authentication Petabyte scale data storage backed by Google Cloud
>   Storage API access throughout Firebase or Google Cloud Storage APIs

Comment: I am using firebase only. I need to upload the mp3 file as mp3 only, not as blob. Is there a way?

Comment: Firebase includes Firebase Storage.  Respectfully, if you are using the Realtime Database to store audio, you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Rightly said, after working further with firebase, i can say the realtime DB should be kept as light as possible. Gives you a tough time as an administrator also.
Storage, on the other hand, can play with Heavy files. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cant upload the audio itself.

In examples i saw, data(for image files) is uploaded in the form of dataURL/Base64 string and the file is reconstructed after download.

Since my audio files are small, 60-70 kb, i am using the same and reconstructing the file again with HTMLAudio element.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a simple way just use these two methods(from the link given below) in your program.

```
private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();//mRecoreder has been declared globally
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");//initiallize LOG_TAG as a string anything u like to get an indication
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;

        uploadAudio();//it is'nt in the link. it has been added by me to upload ur audio to firebase storage cloud 

    }
```

And now to upload the code, add call the method uploadAudio() and its body is :-

private void uploadAudio() {

```
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Audio...");//declare it globally and initialize it with passing the current activity i.e this
mProgressDialog.show();

StorageReference mFilePath = mStorageRef.child("Audio").child("new_audio.3gp");

Uri u = Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName));
mFilePath.putFile(u).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mTextView.setText("Audio has been Uploaded Successfully !!!");
    }
});
```

}

this should b enough for simple audio uploading. Check out the link for further customization.
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html